# Implicit conversion of Object type between unrelated classes at runtime

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

The following VB.Net code is failing at runtime with an `InvalidCastException` error. If I change the type of variable `a1` from `Object` to `class A` then the program executes OK.

I would like to resolve this problem without changing the `Test()` function in the example code below.  I can easily change the definition of `Class A` or `Class B` if required.

```
Public Class A
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal d As A) As B
        Return New B
    End Operator
End Class

Public Class B

End Class

Module X
    Public Sub Test()
        Dim a1 As Object = New A

        Dim b1 As B
        b1 = a1                         ' Fails with System.InvalidCastException

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: It may not be appropriate for your situation but I think the InvalidCastException can be resolved '(without changing the Test() funtion)' by making `Class B` a subclass of `Class A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim a1 As Object = New A
```

Declaring a1 as object seemed like a workaround for the compiler complaining about the code.  But it didn't work, nor could that work since the CLR doesn't go looking for conversion operators at runtime.  The VB.NET Language specification spells out the rules in chapter 9.8.3:

> A type cannot declare a conversion where:
>
> - The source type and the destination type are the same.
> - Both the source type and the destination type are not the type that defines the conversion operator.
> - The source type or the destination type is an interface type.
> - The source type and destination types are related by inheritance (including Object).

The last bullet is your nemesis.  Just use a function instead.

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question, but thanks for giving not only a no answer, but an explanation of **why**.  +1

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was hoping there would be a solution that I had been unable to find.